# Apache camel - How to add headers in recipient list before sending out

Tags: apache-camel

Is it possible to add header to the message based on recipient list before sending out?

Processor

```
@Override
public void process(@NotNull Exchange exchange) {
 exchange.setProperty(PostmanConstant.QUEUE_LIST, "a,b,c");
}
```

Route Context

```
from("amqp:queue:test")
 .process(this.processorRecipientList)
 .recipientList(exchangeProperty(PostmanConstant.QUEUE_LIST), ",");
 .end();
```

For example, adding header information like "owner":"a" to the message before sending out to customer A.